# VS2015 - Xamarin - Error while installing: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm using: `Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015`. I just downloaded the `XamarinEvolve` project from `GitHub`. I need to install the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` library by doing:

```
PM> Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 -Version 23.1.1.1
```

Then I get the error you can see on the following image:

[image]

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: You are installing this NuGet package into your PCL rather than the Android project. Follow @valdetero's answer for how you'd switch this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to install via the console, make sure the you have the Android project selected as the default project.[image]

Or via the menu, right click on the android project and manage nuget packages for that. You can't install an android library into a PCL.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the incorrect project *XamarinEvolve.DataStore.Abstractions* instead of the platform specific *XamarinEvolve.Android*.
You could run the same Package Management Console command with a specific project as a target:

> Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 -Version 23.1.1.1 -ProjectName XamarinEvolve.Android

Or to select the default project to be *XamarinEvolve.Android* from the Package Management Console options strap.